# QT multithreaded QImage change

Tags: multithreading, qt, qimage

I am writing a software which does a lot of image operations / compositing on a lot of (potential big) images.
Multi threading helps a lot speed  wise, but QT does not allow using multiple QPainter on the same image at the same time.
So i would have to do my image operation / compositing in each thread on a copy and then blit it back, which reduces the performance by a lot (depending on the use case obviously).

So i came up with an idea which seem to work, but feels extremely hacky.
I get the target image data (`QImage::bits`) pointer, and provide this to the worker thread.
In the worker thread i recreate a new QImage from the provided pointer. This means, no copy, no blitting.  It seem to work fine, as long as i make sure each pixel/tile is only worked on in one thread and i don't detach the target image.

My question is: Is this safe and are there any other issues that could arise from this approach ?

**Example code**

```
QImage source = ...;
QImage target = ...;
QPainter::CompositionMode compositionMode = QPainter::CompositionMode_SourceOver;

// calculate tiles
QList<QRect> tiles;
for(int y = rect.top(); y < rect.top() + rect.height(); y += tileSize){
    for(int x = rect.left(); x < rect.left() + rect.width(); x += tileSize){
        QRect tile(
                    x, y,
                    x + tileSize > rect.left() + rect.width() ? rect.left() + rect.width() - x : tileSize,
                    y + tileSize > rect.top() + rect.height() ? rect.top() + rect.height() - y : tileSize
        );
        tiles.append(tile);
    }
}

// Get target pixel pointer and do threaded operation on each tile
uchar *targetPix = target.bits();
auto target_size = target.size();
auto targetFormat = target.format();
QList<int> lol = QtConcurrent::blockingMapped(tiles, [&target_size, &targetFormat, &source, targetPix, &compositionMode](const QRect &r){
    QImage tile_target(targetPix, target_size.width(), target_size.height(), targetFormat);
    QPainter p(&tile_target);
    p.setCompositionMode(compositionMode);
    // do you image operations here. For now we just do a simple draw
    p.drawImage(r.topLeft(), source, r);
    return 1; // In reallity this would return sensible data ;)
});
```

(This example increased the speed in my test by about 4.6 times btw. Depends on the operation and system of course.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

This is indeed tricky (but that's often needed when you want bleeding edge performance), but it should be (possible to make it) thread safe (for certain operations). Off course this depends on the operations you perform on the `tile_target`.

*It's up to you that you don't even **access** the bits outside the assigned tile (i.e. the portion of `tile_target` outside the rect `r`).*

### Some considerations

#### Ensure you only *access* the bits of the assigned tile

As `tile_target` refers the whole image, it's up to you to ensure you don't access bits outside this target tile. Some problematic cases:

- **anti-aliasing**: you will probably alter bits of neighboring while performing such an operation
- **Filtering**: operations should as blurring often read the neighboring bits to calculate an 'averaged' value. Reading is not safe either if another thread may be writing the same bit simultaneously.

**Possible solution?**: One option to allow accessing and/or writing to neighboring bits of a tile, is to divide your image in stripes and process your image in two steps:

- first process the even stripes simultaneously
- then process the uneven stripes simultaneously

This procedures allows you to modify half of the neighboring stripes (useful for anti-aliasing) *or* (if nobody writes) to access all the bits of the next and/or previous stripe (useful for filtering purposes).

This shouldn't decrease the efficiency significantly, if you create enough stripes to keep all your cpu(s) busy (i.e. typically twice the number of threads your cpu(s) support).

#### Should I worry about detaching?

That shouldn't be an issue with your current implementation. `QImage::bits` already detaches (if needed) the image (`target`) from any other possibly existing copy. As you perform the concurrent operation by blocking the calling thread. The original image (`target`) will exist at least as long as the `tile_target` images exist.

#### Safer approach

- Use a library that is dedicated to multi-threaded image processing, or at least allow referencing a subimage.
- Pass a copy of the tile (see `QImage::copy`) to each thread and write the result back in the original image (either using mutexes or by performing this operation in the calling thread). Depending on the calculation insensitivity of the image operation, this extra copy may or may not be negligible. For the OP, this doesn't seem a viable option.

Note that those safer approaches may generate (slightly) different results from the single threaded result in case of anti-aliasing or filtering. Those artifacts may be minimized by taking the tiles as large as possible (i.e. create not more tiles than the number of threads your cpu supports)

#### Use GPU

Image processing is often much faster when using your GPU, especially for things like filtering. But that's not something `QImage` supports out of the box.

Comment: Thank you. Am i wrong in thinking the anti-aliasing  issues could be "solved" by additionally copying the "seam" region (4 pixel width/height), do the same operation but with set ClipRect for all of the seam regions BEFORE doing the main operation and then at the end blit the 2nd and 3rd row/column back with composition mode SOURCE ?  
Of course this is only needed if we are using anti-aliasing which i don't do for a lot of composition tasks.

Comment: Also if you have suggestions for good commercial usable image manipulation libraries with multithreading and potential SIMD support PLEASE let me know.  
I looked into many, but they all had their issues of which one is that QTs preferred Pixelformat isn't often supported (ARGB vs RGBA) which means yet another copy/conversion. (Pixman looks nice, but no documentation whatsoever)

Comment: @SleepProgger I'm not sure what you mean by copying, as I thought you were trying to copy nothing at all and instead access the data of the original image in all the worker threads.

Comment: Concerning a library, I don't know. I do not have experience with high performance 'photoshop' like operations. Most of the time, I'm fine with the single threaded version. OpenCV is an 'image' library, but that's more about image recognition.

Comment: I mean in ADDITION to the above add a step where i copy only the seams (where 2 / 4 tiles meet), do the same image operation, but clipped, and blit the middle 2 rows/columns back after my threading stuff is done.  
This should hide the potential visible seams produced by anti aliasing.  Should still  be worth it considering these additional copies are only for some very small areas.

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding exactly what you are proposing. Are you doing the same operation twice? Once for the seams region (in a single thread)? And once per tile (in multiple threads)? Nevertheless, most important is that you ensure you aren't accessing any memory that could be changed by another thread simultaneously.

Comment: Yes, that's the basic idea but only when using anti aliasing obviously. Still should be worth it considering i am working on up to 8k resolution images.

Comment: I'm not sure how much faster that will be compared to just performing the ant-aliasing operations single threaded. Note that I added another idea to my answer to overcome the filtering and anti-aliasing issue by dividing your image in stripes and processing first the even ones and afterwards the uneven ones.